# How to get value from json response in android?

Tags: android, json, android-json

I am facing some problem to get value from my json response. My Json response is as follows:

```
{
    "changed": [
        "username",
        "phone",
        "profile_picture",
        "public_ind"
    ],
    "failed": []
}
```

Please anyone give me some clue so that I can get value from my JSON response.

Comment: What did you do so far?

Comment: look into this [post](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: GOOGLE has prepared so many answers for you... try asking him once?? :)

Comment: I found the solution after using of the solution idea of deniz. I was little confused with json response format of my POST request. I am not so used to with the json. Whatever now it is working... Special thanks to @deniz.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jsonArrayChanged = jsonObject.getJSONArray("changed");
String failed = jsonObject.getString("failed");
for(int i=0;i<jsonArrayChanged.length();i++){
String str = jsonArrayChanged.getString(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works too. Deniz answer is more perfect. I was confused with the json format.

Answer (score 1):

```
//first parse your root object from json string
JSONObject rootObject = new JSONObject(Sring_data);

//get the json array object
JSONArray changedFields = rootObject.getJSONArray("changed");

//iterate the array object
for (int i = 0; i < changedFields.size(); i++) {
Log.d("", changedFields.getString(i)); //here you will get each array items
}

// parse other json objects other than json array
String failedObj = rootObject.getString("failed");
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I was confused with the json format.